# Child routes are refreshing the parent route

Tags: aurelia

My child routes in Aurelia are refreshing the parent route. I don't know what is causing that, someone could help me? I have the following situation:

app.js

```
config.map([

              { route: ':username', moduleId: './components/profile/profile', name: 'profile', nav: false },
            ]);
```

profile.html

```
<div class="profile-post-content">
                <div class="profile-menu">
                    <a active-menu route-href="route: profile; params.bind: { username: username }" class="profile-menu-item menu-active">
                        <label>POSTS</label>
                    </a>
                    <a active-menu route-href="route: following" class="profile-menu-item">
                        <label>FOLLOWING</label
                        <p>${model.following}</p>
                    </a>
                    <a active-menu route-href="route: followers" class="profile-menu-item">
                        <label>FOLLOWERS</label>
                    </a>
                    <a active-menu route-href="route: albums" class="profile-menu-item">
                        <label>ALBUMS</label>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <router-view></router-view>
            </div>
```

profile.js

```
configureRouter(config, router){

        config.map([
          { route: '', moduleId: '../profile/feed', name: 'userfeed', title: 'POSTS', nav: true},
          { route: 'following', moduleId: '../profile/following', name: 'following', title: 'FOLLOWING', nav: true},
          { route: 'followers', moduleId: '../profile/followers', name: 'followers', title: 'FOLLOWERS', nav: true},
          { route: 'albums', moduleId: '../profile/albums', name: 'albums', title: 'ALBUMS', nav: true},

        ]);

        this.router = router;
    }
```

When I click in a link (POST, FOLLOWING, etc), all the profile.html is reloaded.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not posting a form when clicking the links? Can you reproduce this in a new project?

Comment: I'm sure @FabioLuz. That's only a link and the child route only uses GET methods. I'll try to reproduce it.